# Ejabberd install mod_multicast module through web interface

Tags: ios, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

I have installed ejabbered 15.09 on my mac. I am testing it with an iOS app and trying to send a multi cast message. For that my ejabberd server should have the "mod_multicast module".

I am trying to add it via web admin interface (Pic attached):[image]

But no luck.. I have tried editing the ejabberd.yml file in the conf folder and added

mod_multicast:
access:
  multicast:
    all: allow

but still, when I send an IQ

I never see http://jabber.org/protocol/address this protocol in response, which signifies that my ejabbered server allows multicasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use empty option list with `mod_multicast`: []

Comment: Yes, that worked.. Also, I had to add the mod_multicast to the ejabberd.yml file. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149487/ejabberd-cannot-compile-mod-multicast-module

Comment: Well, adding it to the file is needed to make it persistent across restarts.

Comment: Thanks for helping with mutlicast. Also, I am trying to enable mod_proxy65 for file transfer, but, not able to set the configuration right. I edited the ejabberd.yml file and added this

mod_proxy65: hostname: "127.0.0.1"

But when I started the local ejabberd server, error occurs. I guess I am not using the correct format to edit the yml file ?