# Ejabberd cannot compile mod_multicast module

Tags: ejabberd, xmppframework

I am trying to add mod_multicast module to my ejabberd 15.09.

Steps:
1. Get the repo from 'svn co https://svn.process-one.net/ejabberd-modules/'
2. Run ./build.sh command in the directory for mod_multicast '../ejabberd-modules/mod_multicast/trunk'.
3. A .beam file should be created in the ebin directory, but no file is created in my case.

I am following this tutorial for ref: http://www.gettechgo.com/how-to-install-mod_admin_extra-in-ejabberd/#comment-128

Answer (score 0):

`mod_multicast` is integrated in ejabberd since quite some time. There is nothing special to install. You can refer to official documentation: http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#modmulticast

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Mickaël Rémond

I finally got it to work by editing the ejabbred.yml file "/Applications/ejabberd/conf/ejabberd.yml"

Just add: mod_multicast: [], to the yml file and restart your server.

If you want to configure the multicast behavior further, have a look at this: https://svn.process-one.net/ejabberd-modules/mod_multicast/trunk/README.txt